# How can I customize the labels for the pager in Yii?

Tags: php, pagination, yii, paging

I am new to Yii. I want to implement custom pagination. I want to change the appearance of the pager. How do I change the labels of the pager's links?

I want the links to appear like so:

```
<<  <  1  2  3  4  >  >>
```

instead of their default appearance, which is like this:

```
[first] [previous]  1  2  3  4  [next] [last]
```

I am using `CListView` to display the data, which I have set up like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider' => $categoryProjects,
            'itemView' => '_itemDetailsView',           
            'ajaxUpdate'=>false,
        ));
```

Can anyone please tell me how do I start with it? I've seen some posts but unable to get right information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the [`pager`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#pager-detail) property of the `CListView`. By default, this is a [`CLinkPager`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager); you don't need to change that (this component has your needs covered), but you need to configure it:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider' => $categoryProjects,
            'itemView'     => '_itemDetailsView',
            'ajaxUpdate'   => false,
            'pager'        => array(
                                'class'          => 'CLinkPager',
                                'firstPageLabel' => '<<',
                                'prevPageLabel'  => '<',
                                'nextPageLabel'  => '>',
                                'lastPageLabel'  => '>>',
                              ),
        ));
```

**Update:** If you want to "bake in" the above custom configuration to all list views in your application, you have to create a new `CustomListView` component deriving from `CListView`. So you need this class:

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CListView');

class CustomListView extends CListView {
    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->pager = array( 
                            'class'          => 'CLinkPager', 
                            'firstPageLabel' => '<<', 
                            'prevPageLabel'  => '<', 
                            'nextPageLabel'  => '>', 
                            'lastPageLabel'  => '>>', 
                       );
    }
}
```

After including this, you can simply use `CustomListView` as your list widget instead of `zii.widgets.CListView`.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the quick reply. Is there a way to implement this in a single file and it will be applied automatically to all the files. I've used this cListView in many files. And also where can I change the CSS for page numbers?

Comment: @RSK: Please see [this discussion](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/26055-change-the-general-pager-css-for-all-application/) for the CSS. I will shortly be updating the answer for your other question.

Comment: How do I limit the page numbers to 5? The default settings showing 10 page numbers. I've tried this public $maxButtonCount=5; but this isn't working for me. Any suggestions?  Also I want to change the layout a bit to like this   < 1 ... 8 9 10 11 12 .... 30 > because it is showing 10 pages..

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the link:

[Yii2: How to setup pagination style and other labels](https://www.soscodes.com/yii2-how-to-setup-pagination-style-and-other-labels/)

Here you will get most of the options to set up for the custom pagination labels