# Modifiy Pagination style of clistview in yii

Tags: yii, pagination, clistview

How to change clistview pagination style.

Clistview by default give First Previous 1 2 3 4... Next Last.

But i want only Previous and Last Button in Pagination style.

What i should do for this change?

Answer (score 1):

First I think you should read the document of [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView): 
and have a look at these properties: template, pager, pagerCssClass. "template" property will define how to display your CListView, and "pager", "pagerCssClass" will define your pagination. There is also an answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425556/how-can-i-customize-the-labels-for-the-pager-in-yii).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you will have to modify the `createPageButtons` function of `CLinkPager` class of yii framework to do so, there is no shortcut or configuration for it. you will need to create a new component to override or if this is universal requirement through out the project you can change `createPageButtons` function of `CLinkPager'with this code.

```
protected function createPageButtons()
    {
        if(($pageCount=$this->getPageCount())<=1)
            return array();

        list($beginPage,$endPage)=$this->getPageRange();
        $currentPage=$this->getCurrentPage(false); // currentPage is calculated in getPageRange()
        $buttons=array();

        // first page
        $buttons[]=$this->createPageButton($this->firstPageLabel,0,$this->firstPageCssClass,$currentPage<=0,false);

        // prev page
        if(($page=$currentPage-1)<0)
            $page=0;
        $buttons[]=$this->createPageButton($this->prevPageLabel,$page,$this->previousPageCssClass,$currentPage<=0,false);

        // next page
        if(($page=$currentPage+1)>=$pageCount-1)
            $page=$pageCount-1;
        $buttons[]=$this->createPageButton($this->nextPageLabel,$page,$this->nextPageCssClass,$currentPage>=$pageCount-1,false);

        // last page
        $buttons[]=$this->createPageButton($this->lastPageLabel,$pageCount-1,$this->lastPageCssClass,$currentPage>=$pageCount-1,false);

        return $buttons;
    }
```